# Remove empty cells in Excel

Tags: excel

In Excel I want to remove all empty cells so all rows and columns have text.

```
cell1  cell2  cell3
1              peter
...
```

So, I want it like this:

```
cell1 cell2
1     peter
```

How can I remove the empty cells ?

I use ods format, is that relevant?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific example you could do F5 (go to) -> Special.. -> Blanks -> OK. This will select the blank cell - then you could right click -> delete -> move cells left. I'm not sure on the structure of your table though so this may mess other things up?

Comment: don't think it's possible without using .xls format to be honest. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

1.Select the Range in Excel

2.Press [F5].

3.In the resulting Go To dialog box

4.Click Special. Click The Blanks option and click OK.

5.Doing so selects the blank cells (what you might think of as rows) in the selected range.

6.Right Click>Delete> Select your desired option (Moveup,...left..)

Repeat the above untill desired ourput is achieved

Source: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/a-quick-way-to-delete-blank-rows-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a VBA function to do it for you, then you will need something like:

```
Sub ClearBlanks(sheet As Worksheet)

Dim rng As Range
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim firstCol As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim isEmpty As Boolean

    Set rng = sheet.UsedRange
    firstRow = rng.Item(1).row
    firstCol = rng.Item(1).Column

    lastRow = firstRow + rng.Rows.Count - 1
    lastCol = firstCol + rng.Columns.Count - 1

    For i = lastCol To firstCol Step -1
        isEmpty = True
        For j = firstRow To lastRow
            If sheet.Cells(j, i).Value <> "" Then
                isEmpty = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If isEmpty Then
            sheet.Columns(i).Delete
        End If
    Next

    For j = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
        isEmpty = True
        For i = firstCol To lastCol
            If sheet.Cells(j, i).Value <> "" Then
                isEmpty = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If isEmpty Then
            sheet.Rows(j).Delete
        End If
    Next

    For i = firstCol - 1 To 1 Step -1
        sheet.Columns(i).Delete
    Next

    For i = firstRow - 1 To 1 Step -1
        sheet.Rows(i).Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that this only deletes columns or rows that are totally empty, thus preserving table structure if only some cells in a row or column are empty.